# Using table or div

Tags: html, tabular

What is the best practice when building our web page div or table?

Someone says the div is recommended, but I found it is not easy to control the size and alignment with div.

What is your opinion?

Comment: Please make more specific examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What's the deal with those question marks?

Comment: @Cody Gray: they're laid out with divs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It depends entirely on what you're wanting to display**:

- `<DIV>` and `<SPAN>` is for page layout
- `<Table>` is for displaying *tabular* data (such as data points etc)

The days of using `<table>` for whole page layouts is gone - and you should be discouraged for using them for this reason.

HTML tags are meant to be [*semantic*](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=define:+semantic&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).  This means **describing the data** it contains - **not how to display it** (this is for stylesheets to handle)

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with TABLE - it's just that it was historically overused for the wrong thing.  In general, try to use TABLE for true tables of data, use DIV and SPAN for logical block or inline containers of content.

Answer (score 2):

First read this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

In my opinion (which I'm sure some people will groan about subjective questions being asked on Stack Overflow), but I prefer using `div`'s. A `div` tag is one tag, a table takes many tags to create a correctly marked-up table element.

A lot of websites in the 1990s were built with tables, but the thinking nowadays in to use `div`s.

Answer (score 2):

Tables should only be used to display data in a tabular way.  For layout and design it is best practise to use divs and stylesheets.

Controlling the divs using stylesheets can take a while if you're not used to it, but it's quite easy to pick up.

You'll be thankful you did it later when the client wants the whole site redesigned and it means you don't have to undo the entire page in order to make the required changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that div is definitely the industry standard for website layouts. They can be quite cumbersome to work with at first but once you get your head around how they are positioned then you will never look at tables again.

Try this tutorial for moving from tables to divs. http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Web-Style-Sheets/DIV-Based-Layout-with-CSS/

Comment: The link no longer works. Can you please please post a new link to the matter in question? Thank you!